# Android First Fragment

Tags: android

My first fragment with only background color and a TextVew does not appear on screen. Subsequent fragments appear. Why?

I expected it to appear after placing a breakpoint following the initial processing. It did not. The fragments use constraint layouts. The main XML is a frame layout. I added a container to the frame moving its container "id" to the container with the first frame as its initial fragment. The application runs fine without the initial fragment appearing but I would like to know why without days of research, so I signed up on this site to ask.

Answer: The fragment got a reference without its onCreate method being executed. Why?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)